# How to convert 01/01/2012 01:00:00 to utc?

Tags: python, utc

I have tried to convert my time data so that that my python script can read this data. I have tried

```
Time.append(row[1])
Time = Time[1:]
    Time = [str (i) for i in Time]

datetime_Time = datetime.datetime ("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S") #pharsing the time
    print (Time)
```

I have tried passing the data as a float and as an integer too.But as my data uses "/" and :, this therefore is causing an error and would appreciate if anyone could show me how to read this data

Comment: `newstr = oldstr.replace("/", "")`

Comment: What is in `Time` and how is it being used (or desired to be used)? The `datetime` constructor can not make a `datetime` from a format string, or any string for that matter. Take a look at [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse a time string into a `datetime.datetime` object.

Comment: Also, your date string contains no timezone information, so converting to UTC makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
import datetime
s = "01/01/2012 01:00:00"
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
20120101 01:00:00
```